# Python IPv6 Bytes To Address

Tags: python, ipv6, pythonista

I am running python on the iOS App Pythonista 3.
When I try to get an IPv6 address it ends up
returning bytes rather than a formatted address.
Right now I am trying to find a way to either get the address properly without bytes, or to find a way to make the bytes become the address.
Here is the code I ran to get the address:

```
def getIPv6Addr(input):
    return socket.getaddrinfo(input, None, socket.AF_INET6)
```

and here was the output:

```
[(30, 2, 17, '', (30, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&\x07\xf8\xb0@\x00\x08\x14')), (30, 1, 6, '', (30, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&\x07\xf8\xb0@\x00\x08\x14'))]
```

Edit: The alternative solution is to find what type of encoding is being used to turn this data into bytes.

```
What Makes:
2607:f8b0:4000:814::200e
become
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&\x07\xf8\xb0@\x00\x08\x14
```

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238934/getaddrinfo-in-iphone The 2-tuple you are getting certainly doesn't look like anything that specifies an IPv6 address.

Comment: I'm not seeing similar results from socket.getaddrinfo in python2 or python3 on Linux.  That surprises me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ipaddress` module that is included with python. Just pass the bytes to the constructor of `ipaddress.IPv6Address` and you'll get an object representing the address and giving you lots of possibilities to print and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

there is a quick way if you use this package:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

a = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&\x07\xf8\xb0@\x00\x08\x14'


print(smart_str(a))
```

Comment: While attempting running smart_str I found out that pythonista + django doesn't work because django calls subprocesses and iOS blocks subprocessing. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

## Solved!

I encoded the bytes with hex and it made
it become the address!

```
>>> getIPv6Addr("google.com")[0][4][1].encode("hex")
'0000000000002607f8b040000811'
```